# Question about parallel structures

Tags: nouns, adjectives, gerunds, coordinating-conjunctions

One of the tasks that we have to do on PTE exam is to paraphrase a writtent text. I have prepared a template for myslef which is

**While the impacts of N and N such as N and N are important, the effects of N and N such as N and N are significant, and the influences of N and N such as N and N are remarkable.**

Now, my questions is, when using this template as there is a coordinating conjunction of " and" should all the noun phrases be in the same structure, namely both gerund, infiniting, adj+noun and so forth? Or there is no need for that?

Example :

While the impacts of m**aking money and modern approaches**
Such as **Different books and collections of assignments**

Comment: Related: [_black and lab mouse_ ... using coordinated adjectives and attributive nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259361/black-and-lab-mouse-using-coordinated-adjectives-and-attributive-nouns). // Also, ing-forms and prototypical nouns can co-occur in (at least some) coordinate structures: [NHS: 'Building and demolition works at St George’s'](https://www.stgeorges.nhs.uk/newsitem/building-and-demolition-works-at-st-georges/). But too broad.

Comment: The specified "template" would probably ***always*** result in virtually unreadable text, no matter what noun phrases were used instead of all those Ns. So as regards the merits and/or constraints of "parallelism", the only thing I would say is three occurrences of the construction ***N and N such as N and N*** in a single utterance is just ridiculous.

Comment: I'd use "Different books and collections of assignments," as easy to understand, and not "making money and modern approaches," as hard to understand.